# Parallel Fsharp vs parallel C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, f#

I copy pasted the parallel portion of this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx#Anchor_0). I measured the time in a i3 processor and the measurement was 37563ms. I rewrote the same program in Fsharp like this

```
 let rec fib x = if x<2 then x else fib(x-1)+fib(x-2)
 let time_call f = 
 let b=System.Environment.TickCount in
 let x = f() in
 System.Environment.TickCount-b

 let fibs() =
  Async.Parallel[for i in [24;26;41;42]->async{return fib   i}]|>Async.RunSynchronously

 [<EntryPoint>]
 let main argv = 
 printfn "%A" (time_call fibs)
 0 // return an integer exit code
```

And the time that I measured was 4735ms. Am I doing something wrong or Fsharp parallel programming is so much faster?

Comment: I corrected the code please remove duplicate. The question is about comparison of C++ PPL and F# parallel functionality.

Comment: The `in` syntax is rarely used. However, the C++ version is taking too long, can you post the code to that as well.

Comment: To give you an idea I get about  1750ms in F# and 1233ms for parallel time in C++ which is slightly faster than .NET. Something more heavy, like a mandelbrot could be an interesting example for comparison.

Comment: Good to post full c++ and F# code otherwise one can just speculate. In addition, .NET does optimize well written tight loops rather well but can fall far behind C++ code if the problem fits well with AVX (.NET has some minimal support for SSE2 but for more complex algorithms it isn't enough) or the problem requires precise control of the memory layout (in order to utilise the cache well).

Comment: Also, I wish we stop using extremely inefficient fibonacci implementations as a benchmark. It's our industry version of cheating on diesel-emission tests.

Comment: I found the error. I recompiled F# and C++ code in Release mode so the result are: C++(2328ms) F#(2922ms).

Comment: If you want to make the F# code much faster, try using a tail-recursive function like the following:

    `let tailFib n =
        let rec tailFib' a1 a2 count = 
            if (count < 0L) then 1L
            elif (count = 0L) then a1 + a2
            else tailFib' a2 (a1 + a2) (count - 1L)
        tailFib' 1L 1L (n - 2L)`

Comment: The c++ version is locking on the results2.push_back, the F# version is creating an array for each result such that there is no synchronisation needed to return a result.

Answer (score 4):

`fibs`/`f` is a value in your example, not a function.  `fibs` is getting computed before `main` even starts.

You want e.g.

```
let x = printfn "%A" (f()) in
```

and

```
let fibs() =
```

Comment: I changed `let x = printfn "%A" f in `to let x = f() in` and `let fibs =` to `let fibs() =` and the time increased to 4735ms which is less than 37563ms. So is F# so much faster?